# create dynamic number callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

i have problem to create deep number of callback function in javascript dynamically. For example i have function like this.

```
function process(value, callback) {
    console.log('process ' + value)
    callback()

}

function complete() {
    console.log('complete')
}

function running(count){
     // number process function is two
    if (count==2) {
        process('number one', function () {
            process('number two', function () {
                complete()  => // last callback is closed by complete function
         })
      })
    }

    // number process function is three
    if (count==3) {
         process('number one', function () {
             process('number two', function () {
                process('number three', function () {
                    complete() => // last callback is closed by complete function
                })
             })
        })
      }
   }  

running(3);
```

Output :

> process number one
>
> process number two
>
> process number three
>
> completed

i want to create number callback is dynamic and closed by complete function, not using `if/switch` command, how to do that? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use recursion and that will exit and run `complete` when the count param is zero otherwise it will call `process` function.

```js
function process(value, callback) {
  console.log('process ' + value)
  callback()

}

function complete() {
  console.log('complete')
}

const p = ['three', 'two', 'one']

function running(count) {
  if (count) {
    process(`number ${p[count - 1]}`, () => {
      running(count - 1)
    })
  } else {
    complete()
  }
}

running(3);
```

Comment: thank you @Nenad Vracar.. for fast response...your answer work for me

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for this.

I create the three promises using a `for loop` and put them in an array. The `resolve` functions write the index to the console. Use `Promise.all` to execute them in order and use `finally` to write completed.

With the promise we don't need to provide a callback function.

```js
function process(value) {
    console.log('process ' + value)
}

function complete() {
    console.log('complete')
}

const textInt = ['one', 'two', 'three']
function running(count){
    const promiseArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      promiseArray[new Promise(function(){
        process(textInt[i], function(){});
      })];
    }
    
    Promise.all(promiseArray).finally(complete)
}      
  
running(3);
```

Comment: i am sorry @Mouser.. if i setup settimeout() for asyncronous ini process(), this not working too

Answer (score 1):

You can do without using callback in this case:

```js
var processNames = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

function process(value) {
    console.log('process ' + value);
}

function complete() {
    console.log('complete');
}

function running(count){
    for (var index = 0; index < count; index++) {
        var name = 'number ' + processNames[index];
        
        process(name);
    }
    
    complete();
}  

running(3);
```

Comment: i am sorry @Tan.. if i setup settimeout() for asyncronous ini process(), thiis not working